# error - ./node_modules/web3-eth-contract/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:26:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'http'

Tags: javascript, next.js, solidity, polygon, moralis

I am working on **Next.js**

**Error** which I am receiving =>

```
    error - ./node_modules/web3-eth-contract/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:26:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'http'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/web3-eth-contract/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js
./node_modules/web3-eth-contract/node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js
./node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@toruslabs/fetch-node-details/dist/fetchNodeDetails.esm.js
./node_modules/@toruslabs/torus-embed/dist/torus.esm.js
./node_modules/@web3auth/torus-evm-adapter/dist/torusEvmAdapter.esm.js
./node_modules/@web3auth/web3auth/dist/web3auth.esm.js
./node_modules/moralis/lib/browser/Web3Connector/Web3AuthConnector.js
./node_modules/moralis/lib/browser/MoralisWeb3.js
./node_modules/moralis/lib/browser/Parse.js
./node_modules/moralis/index.js
./node_modules/react-moralis/lib/index.esm.js
./pages/_app.js
```

My **package.json** =>

```
        {
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.8",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.5.0",
    "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.7.5",
    "@web3auth/web3auth": "^0.6.3",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "elasticsearch": "^16.7.3",
    "elasticsearch-browser": "^16.7.1",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^5.6.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.1",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "ipfs-http-client": "^56.0.1",
    "magic-sdk": "^8.1.0",
    "moralis": "^1.5.5",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-moralis": "^1.3.4",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "web3modal": "^1.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "eslint": "8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "tailwind": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  }
}
```

`next.config.js` =>

```
   module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  return {
    ...defaultConfig,

    webpack: (config) => {
      config.resolve = {
        ...config.resolve,
        fallback: {
          "fs": false,
          "path": false,
          "os": false,
          "crypto": false,
        }
      }
      return config
    },
  }
}
```

`_app.js` =>

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer'
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis"
import { ServerUrl, AppId } from "../config"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <MoralisProvider appId={AppId} serverUrl={ServerUrl}>
      <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
        <Head>
          <title> Certified-Cliché</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <nav className="border-b p-6 place-content-center">
          <p className="text-4xl font-bold mt-4  ">
            Certified-Cliché
          </p>
          <div className="flex mt-4">
            <Link href="/home">
              <a className="mr-4 text-pink-500">
                Home
              </a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/create-certificate">
              <a className="mr-6 text-pink-500">
                Create Certificate
              </a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/transferred-certificate">
              <a className="mr-6 text-pink-500">
                Transferred Certificate
              </a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/my-certificates">
              <a className="mr-6 text-pink-500">
                My Certificates
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </MoralisProvider>
  )
}
```

export default MyApp

What I tried till now =>

1. Deleting `node_modules` and `npm i`.
2. `npm i http`
3. Deleting the `.next` build folder and starting again.
4. Setting the browser- `crypto:false` in `package.json`

Most the solutions I found were for the Angular.js.

If you require any more information, then please let me know.
Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error you have based on [Next.js website](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found):

A module not found error can occur for many different reasons:

- The module you're trying to import is not installed in your dependencies
- The module you're trying to import is in a different directory
- The module you're trying to import has a different casing
- The module you're trying to import uses Node.js specific modules, for example dns, outside of getStaticProps / getStaticPaths / getServerSideProps

Please check out the link for possible fixes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggesting this. But I am not able to find anything helpful in this, can you please provide some other source or solution?

Comment: @YashGarg Can you provide a link to your full repo?

Comment: Here it is => https://github.com/Megabyte-143/certified_cliche/tree/dev

Comment: @YashGarg this isn't the same repo

Comment: It's the same repo, you may check the client directory in it. NOTE: It's not upto date because many others are contributing in the project in the same directory.

Comment: If it's not exactly the same, I'm sorry I can't help. I had this same issue with a project I was working on and it took me a long while to know what the real issue was maybe a week or two. Check your code to see if there's imports that you have but not using them and remove or comment them out. Also, check if your dependencies are up-to-date. That is what I can help with for now.